# Stable Diffusion API with React issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, stable-diffusion

I'm new here and would appreciate your help.
I am currently experiencing an issue with the stablediffusion API.
Here's my code.

```
const request_body = {
    key: process.env.REACT_APP_STABLE_DIFFUSION_API,
    prompt: "ultra realistic close up portrait ((beautiful pale cyberpunk female with heavy black eyeliner))",
    negative_prompt: null,
    width: "512",
    height: "512",
    samples: 1,
    num_inference_steps: "20",
    seed: null,
    guidance_scale: 7.5,
    safety_checker: "yes",
    multi_lingual: "no",
    panorama: "no",
    self_attention: "no",
    upscale: "no",
    embeddings_model: null,
    webhook: null,
    track_id: null,
};

const generateImage = async () => {
  const generateResponse = await axios.post(
    "https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v5/text2video",
    request_body
  );
  console.log(generateResponse.data);
};
```

It's not just an issue with the API key. The result is an error.
The status shows an error and the error message needs a seconds value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v3/text2image
```

Hey @theavocoder, you used the wrong API. The one you used is for text2video.
Try using the API above.

Answer (score 0):

**Add seconds parameter in request_body to specify the duration-related parameter if it is intended for video rendering.**

```js
const request_body = {
    key: process.env.REACT_APP_STABLE_DIFFUSION_API,
    prompt: "ultra realistic close up portrait ((beautiful pale cyberpunk female with heavy black eyeliner))",
    negative_prompt: null,
    width: "512",
    height: "512",
    samples: 1,
    num_inference_steps: "20",
    seed: null,
    guidance_scale: 7.5,
    safety_checker: "yes",
    multi_lingual: "no",
    panorama: "no",
    self_attention: "no",
    upscale: "no",
    embeddings_model: null,
    webhook: null,
    track_id: null,
    seconds: 10, // Add duration in seconds
};
```

Add an exception handler for detailed error insights:

```
const generateImage = async () => {
  try {
    const generateResponse = await axios.post(
      "https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v5/text2video",
      request_body
    );
    console.log(generateResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error Status:", error.response.status);
    console.error("Error Message:", error.response.data);
  }
};
```